# how to find differentiation of this integral of pdf with respect of another variable?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have a probability distribution function of a continuous random variable $X$ as $f(x)$ and we define a function $g(t)$ in terms of $f$ such that

## $g(t)$ = $\int_0^t$$xf(x)dx$

where
I want to minimise the function $g(t)$ and thus want to calculate differential of $g(t)$ wrt $t$ and I came up with

## $tf(t)$

which seems to be incorrect and there are more terms in the solution and I'm not sure how do I proceed with this.

How do I find the differential of $g(t)$?

Comment: Since it's a pdf and thus non-negative this is trivially minimized at $t = 0$ since we're bounded below by $0$

Comment: @Vercingetorix Im more interested in the differential because its part of a bigger problem.

Comment: The derivative is indeed $tf(t)$, which follows trivially by the fundamental theorem of calculus. In fact, it basically is the statement of the FTC

Comment: @Vercingetorix you're right, I misinterpreted some terms and assumed that my answer was incorrect. Which is indeed correct. If you want to answer it, I can accept it.